# Printing a ULARGE_INTEGER to a console

Tags: c, windows, winapi, types

I would like to print the size of the root volume set by GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(...), but the value it gives me is a ULARGE_INTEGER. What is the best way to go about printing this to a console as a decimal number? I am using plain C and Windows API functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742(v=vs.85).aspx, I'm pretty sure it'd be something like this:

```
printf("%llu\n", some_ularge_integer.QuadPart);
```

Comment: Of course, as long as the compiler you're using supports `long long` variables. (You may have to make sure you're using the right extensions if it doesn't have that enabled by default [so you may want to specify what you meant by "plain C"].)